# Убрать ключ из массива

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
massive = massive.pairs;
 massive.pairs.splice(massive.pairs.ltc_btc, 1);
 console.log(massive);
```

по разному пробовал; так и не смог получить желаемый результат.
честно гуглил, не нашел ответ.

у меня есть массив с разными ключами (ltc_btc, eth_btc...)
Мне надо убрать ненужные мне ключи.
Как убрать ключ из массива ?

```
 "pairs": {
        "ltc_btc": {
            "decimal_places": 8,
            "max_price": 10000,
            "fee": 0.2
        },
        "nmc_btc": {
            "decimal_places": 8,
            "max_price": 10000,
            "fee": 0.2
        },
```

Comment: Может быть у тебя массив объектов ? Покажи свой массив.

Comment: добавил в шапку вопроса

Comment: какой результат ожидается?

Comment: просто чтоб весь объект с ltc_btc исчез

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не массив у тебя, а объект.
Вот так можно удалить:

```
delete massive.pairs.ltc_btc;
```